# OAuth2 - Got token, how to send with POST request?

Tags: node.js, oauth

Working with a vendor with minimal API and new to OAuth2. Using npm packages oauth and request.

Creating a node module which would post data from a database to the server's API.

I've got the authorization token, but now I'm unsure how to send that with the data post request. The vendor server is responding with a simple `Cannot POST /accounts/import`.

So - how do I send the OAuth2 token back with the post data to the server?

```
var request = require('request'),
  clcreds = require('../../creds/creds.js');


var OAuth = require('oauth');
var OAuth2 = OAuth.OAuth2;
var oauth2 = new OAuth2(clcreds.clientId, clcreds.clientSecret, 'https://URL.com/', null, 'token', null);
oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken('', {
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}, function(e, access_token, refresh_token, results) {
  console.log(e, access_token, refresh_token, results);

  request.post('https://URL.com/accounts/import', {
    "accounts": [{
      ...
    }]
  }, function(e, r, body) {
    //returns Cannot POST /accounts/import
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most resource servers support [RFC 6750, 2.1. Authorization Request Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1). If your server supports it, you can pass an access token to the server by adding `Authorization` header like below.

```
Authorization: Bearer YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN
```

If your server does not support any means defined in [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750), you have to ask the implementor of the server about how to pass an access token to the server.